# Cannot invoke batch file from Web service hosted on IIS

Tags: web-services, batch-file, iis-8

I created a web service and hosted it on IIS server. 
Web service has to invoke a batch file ( which in turn invokes an exe ) taking an Xml input.

Batch file and exe to be invoked by batch file are placed in the Web service folder. I'm using an already present xml as input for the batch file.

This code works on the local machine but not after the webservice is hosted on IIS server and I invoke it from the browser.

```
public string InvokeDACS()

{

    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(Server.MapPath("~/SRSApplication/Application/SRS_TCNX.bat"));

    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

    string path = Server.MapPath("~/SRS Application/Input/98765433.xml");

    pInfo.Arguments = path;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pInfo);

    return "s";

}
```

Please help in figuring out a way for invoking a batch file from web service.

Comment: Any log/error output indicating what failed?

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask]. "Doesn't work" is not a proper problem statement.